# Identify runs of repeated list items

Tags: python

I have a sequence of items in list. I want to identify runs of identical elements and print their starting and ending locations. For example, with:

```
content=[c,c,c,c,f,f,f,f,c,c,b,b,b,b...]
```

I want the output to be like:

```
1-4 c
5-8 f
9-10 c
```

and so on and so forth. Here's what I have so far:

```
x=len(content)-1
i=0
y=0
z=0
for i in range(0,x):
  if(content[i]==content[i+1]):
    y=y+1
    z=i-1
  else:
    print y
    print content[z]
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt at using `if` and `else` to solve this?

Comment: could you please provide concrete examples of what you have attempted?

Comment: x=len(content)
i=0
for i in (o,x):
  
  if(content[i]==content[i+1]):
    
  else:
    print i+1

Comment: can you include it in your original post properly formatted? thanks

Comment: included the code I am trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is not your `if` and `else`, but rather how you're looping. You seem to be missing a call to `range`, and only have the call's arguments. Try:

```
for i in range(0, x):
```

The `if` and `else` blocks will now be reached, and you just need to adjust them to track the values you care about. If you want the start and and of consecutive runs of items, you don't actually need both parts. Try this:

```
run_start = 0
for i in range(len(content)-1):
    if content[i] != content[i+1]: # only one branch needed, nothing to do when items are ==
        print "{}-{} {}".format(run_start+1, i+1, content[i])
        run_start = i+1
print "{}-{} {}".format(run_start+1, len(content), content[-1]) # extra code for the last run
```

This will print out ranges like `3-3` if there's only one item in a run. If you don't want that, you may need to add another `if` statement to check that `i` and `run_start` are not equal (and either print something else, or skip that run if they are).

I find that it's very helpful to you use meaningful variable names, where possible. In this case, I'm using `run_start` rather than `y` or `x` for that reason.

Comment: I edited those things. Still I am not able to work with it. I gues there is something wrong with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Blckknght's solution is great. My own version is just more verbose, in case that helps you with understanding the logic behind the whole process. What you need to do is iterate through each element of the list and store it in `current` and compare that with the `last` (last known object) coming from a previous iteration. If they are the same, then you increment the `range_end` index. If they are different, then it means a new range is starting, so you must do several things:

- print what you have learned so far, as far as `range_begin`, `range_end` and `current` element.
- store the `current` element in `last`, as it is the first element of the new sequence
- set both range indexes `range_begin` and `range_end` to the current `i`

To make the whole process work, you need to initialize `last` before looping to the first element of the `content` list.

Also, since the index `i` is 0-based, when we print both `range_begin` and `range_end` we just increase them by 1.

```
content=['c','c','c','c','f','f','f','f','c','c','b','b','b','b']
range_begin=0
range_end=0
last=content[0]  # store the first element as the last known
for i in range(0, len(content)):
  current = content[i]  # get the element from the list
  if last != current:   # compare to the last known, if different
    print "{}-{} {}".format(range_begin+1, range_end+1, last)  # print
    last = current      # store the current as last known
    range_begin = i     # reset the ranges to the current index
    range_end = i
  else:
    range_end = i       # if they are the same, just extend the range_end
```

Check it also on:
https://eval.in/575899

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve a non-trivial (if yet fairly simple) problem and I recommend you get assistance from the standard library. The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module provides the [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function which does almost what you need. Given a sequence of elements *x*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*n*</sub> it will yield you pairs (*k*, *g*) of a key *k* and a non-empty lazy sequence of elements *g* that compare equal to *k*. (You can convert *g* into an ordinary list by applying [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) to it.)

Let's try it out:

```
from itertools import groupby
items = "ccccffffccbbbb"
for (k, g) in groupby(items):
    print k, list(g)
```

Output:

```
c ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
f ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f']
c ['c', 'c']
b ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

This looks already quite useful but we have to compute the begin and end index from the list of equal items. Luckily, we know the  begin index for the first group – it is 1. If we know the begin index for any group, we also know its end index, which is the begin index plus the length of the group minus 1. The begin index of the next group will be the begin index of the current group plus the length of the current group.

This is all we need:

```
from itertools import groupby
items = "ccccffffccbbbb"
offset = 1
for (k, g) in groupby(items):
    length = len(list(g))  # simple and does the job but not as efficient as it could be
    print '{}-{} {}'.format(offset, offset + length - 1, k)
    offset += length
```

Output:

```
1-4 c
5-8 f
9-10 c
11-14 b
```